# Match list indices with strings to create a working deck of cards

Tags: python, list, function

This is for a school assignment. I have a list from 0 to 51 that represents a deck of cards. My goal is to make a function that allows the user to input a number from 0 to 51 and every number will match a card in the deck. For example if the number 0 represents the ace of diamonds, 1 the 2 of diamonds and so on...
Every 14 numbers the suit should change to the next one. This is what I have so far:

```
deck = list(range(52))

def cardid(card_num):
        suits = ["diamonds", "hearts", "clubs", "spades"]
        cards = ["ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "jack","queen", "king"]
```

I'm stuck trying to match numbers with cards. The assignment instructions suggest to use floor division and the division remainder but wouldn't that require quite a lot of if statements? is there another (simpler) way of doing this? Pls keep in mind I have just started using python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually pretty straight forward. You need two indices, one corresponding to the list of suits, and the other corresponding to the list of cards. Here is how you can get them:

```
def cardid(card_num):
    suits = ["diamonds", "hearts", "clubs", "spades"]
    cards = ["ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "jack","queen", "king"]
    suits_index = int(card_num/13) # Here's your floor division
    cards_index = card_num%13      # And here's your division remainder 
    print ("The card is",cards[cards_index],"of",suits[suits_index])
```

To verify, just call the function as follows:

```
card_num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
# Just to make sure the input is valid for the scope of this function
if card_num >=0 and card_num < 52:
    cardid(card_num)
```